# Mapbox Studio : add label from uploaded layer

Tags: label, layer, mapbox-studio

I have added district JSON in the basemap and removed the default label. Now I want the labels from the uploaded JSON. I am not able to add text field in style to show the label. Can anyone help me to add label from the uploaded file.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lo2X5.png)

Comment: What you have tried so far? Can you show us?

Comment: I have removed the label from the base map and uploaded the shapefile for my study area as the boundary